# Finding pairs of sets so that their union has a specific size

Tags: algorithm, scala, optimization, set, knapsack-problem

I have a variable like follow:

```
var L_s = collection.mutable.Set[collection.mutable.Set[Int]]()
```

and I want to find the union of sets of different size .

Please Note : All the sets in L_s will be of same size that is k-1 when we want to find union of size k.

As of now I am doing the following :

```
for(i <- L_s){
 for (j <- L_s){
     if((i.union(j)).size == k)
        {
       res.+=(i.union(j))
        }
    }
  }
```

This operation is taking a lot of time if `L_s` has many sets. I wanted to know what is the most efficient way to do this operation.

Comment: Are there any more characteristics of the sets that we should know about? Is anything known about the elements of the sets, i.e., how many different elements are there in total in relation to `k`? Is it theoretically possible that all sets have different elements, i.e., they are completely disjoint?

Comment: No,  Only thing as I mentioned is  All the sets in L_s will be of same size that is k-1 when we want to find union of size k. So if i can remove any redundant computation which my posted method does would help in quickening up my algorithm. The problem which I am currently working on generates lot of sets. I am trying to lower that number. I think the number of sets are the root cause for the slowness.

Answer (score 1):

Since `union` is commutative (`a union b == b union a`) you're doing twice as many operations as needed, and you're repeating the `union` operation again when the target size is found, and every `Set` gets `union` with itself.  These inefficiencies can be eliminated.

```
L_s.toVector.combinations(2).map(x => x(0) union x(1)).filter(_.size == k).toSet
```

Comment: This solution is fetching me results. However the the time is almost same. I may have to optimize other part of my code. I am trying to find frequent item sets. I will find a way to reduce the number of sets in my L_s variable. That may help speed up the code.

Comment: Indeed. The workload is quadratic in relation to the size of `L_s`. Anything that can done to reduce that will have a big payoff.

Answer (score 0):

There are basically two opportunities to speed up your algorithm:

1. Speed up a single comparison of two sets
2. Reduce the total number of required comparisons

With comparison I mean the check whether the union of both sets has size `k`.

The first one is the simpler part and I mentioned it in my previous answer. You don't have to actually compute the union and check its size. It is sufficient to know the size of the intersection (not the actual intersection, only its size). Run through the elements of the first set and count how many occur in the second (very efficient lookup). If the intersection has size `k - 2` you found a pair of sets the conforms to your requirement. You should break the loop whenever you have found two elements not in the second set because you will never reach intersection size `k - 2` from there.

This works because two sets with the required property have all elements in common except for one in each set. This means set 1 has exactly one element not in set 2 and vice versa.

You can also exploit this property to limit the number of comparisons. The idea is the following. Your sets contain integers that can be ordered. If a pair of sets qualifies and you consider only the lowest two integers of each set, let's call it the prefix, the prefixes have at least one integer in common. Anything else would be a contradiction to your requirement.

You can now index all sets by their lowest and second lowest integer in advance. I.e., you build two maps of type `Map[Int, Set[Set[Int]]`, let's call them `setsByLowestMember` and `setsBySecondLowestMember`. When you now loop through all sets for testing, instead of testing a set against every other set, you only test against those sets having the lowest or second lowest member equal to the lowest or second lowest of the current set.

Example: The current (ordered) set under consideration is `{ 3, 7, 9, ...}`. You check against all of `setsByLowestMember(3)`, `setsByLowestMember(7)`, `setsBySecondLowestMember(3)` and `setsBySecondLowestMember(7)`.

Depending on your data this may significantly speed up your algorithm. However, if your sets tend to have a very large intersection in general, it might not help that much. If it helps, it can be further improved (there still some checks done twice with the above approach).